# Linux recv returns data not seen in Wireshark capture

Tags: network-programming, wireshark

I am receiving data through a TCP socket and although this code has been working for years, I came across a very odd behaviour trying to integrate a new device (that acts as a server) into my system:

Before receiving the HTTP Body response, the recv() kernel function gives me strange characters like '283' or '7b'.

- I am actually debuging with gdb and I can see that the variables hold these values right after recv() was called (so it is not just what printf shows me)
- I always read byte-after-byte (one at a time) with the recv() function and the returned value is always positive.
- This first line of the received HTTP Body cannot be seen in Wireshark (!) and is also not expected to be there. In Wireshark I see what I would expect to receive.
- I changed the device that sends me the data and I still receive the exact same values
- I performed a clean debug build and also tried a release version of my programm and still get the exact same values, so I assume these are not random values that happened to be in memory.
- i am running Linux kernel 3.2.58 without the option to upgrade/update.

I am not sure what other information i should provide and I have no idea what else to try.

Comment: Hard to debug code without it.

Comment: I think that you mean byte-after-byte. Not bit-afte-bit.

Comment: Yes, I meant byte ;)

Answer (score 1):

Found it. The problem is that I did not take the [**Transfer-Encoding**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) into consideration, which is **chunked**. I was lucky because also older versions of Wireshark were showing these bytes in the payload so other people also posted similar problems in the wireshark forum.

Those "strange" bytes show you the payload length that you are supposed to receive. When you are done reading this amount of bytes, you will receive again a number that tells you whether you should continue reading (and, again, how many bytes you will receive). As far as I understood, this is usefull when you have data that change dynamically and you might want to continuously get their current value.